# Where can I find the datasheet for this LED driver IC?

Tags: identification, led-driver

This IC (in the middle of the board, has seven terminals) is from a LED driver circuit:

[image]

And here is a closer look:

[image]

It has the text "9504DB 6C70Y" on it. I need help finding its datasheet.

**Edit:** after some googling, it seems to be some kind of a 555 timer. Now I need to identify which pins are which.

Comment: Nice job on this identification question ;) Close-up detail pic of the part + info on where it's found. Now hopefully someone can recognize that manufacturer's mark ...

Comment: Thank you :) I would like to add it's probably a Chinese one since the driver itself is Chinese.

Comment: Can you please add a picture of the bottom side?

Comment: @Jens it is soldered to the board.

Comment: @WaisKamal I meant the other side of the board, not the chip, just to see the connections between the components.

Comment: The board rectifies and filters the line input. Then a buck converter controller with a constant current output drives the string of LEDs in series. I don't see a separate MOSFET on the PWB, so the MOSFET is inside the IC. The circuit would be something like this: https://www.circuitsarena.com/2014/11/led-driver-circuit.html

Comment: @Jens here it is: front - https://i.imgur.com/NAL9VGW.jpg, back - https://i.imgur.com/6UvrBJ4.jpg.

Comment: @Mattman944 so that component below the capacitor is an inductor? It looks like a transformer, but its two input terminals are shorted together and connected to the negative Vout, and its other two terminals are also shorted out and connected to the positive Vout through a diode.

Comment: @WaisKamal Yup. A coil. It probably has 4 pins for better mounting. If I see well, at the pcb's output cables (red/black), the "coil" is on one side (black cable) and the other side (red cable) goes straight to the rectifier bridge, and the D5 diode is in series with the coil. It totally makes sense if that's a coil and the chip is a switching driver - see https://i.imgur.com/eu7QS52.png - I tried a quick analysis how switching the coil forms a controlled "-" for the LEDs while the "+" goes straight from the bridge.

Comment: @WaisKamal - Yes, an inductor. Besides quetzalcoatl's good explaination, it is also labeled L1.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl the diagram is very informative, thanks :). So the IC's main function is to switch between charging and discharging the inductor.

Comment: An at least pin compatible IC is this: https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1351316/Winsemi/WS9002/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JD semi ([www.jdsemi.cn](http://www.jdsemi.cn))

Use google translate: https://wk.baidu.com/view/d1982f502d3f5727a5e9856a561252d380eb209b

Comment: Thank you. Google Translate does not seem to work on this site, but this is indeed helpful.

Comment: No problem! I use the translator in Safari, works ok.

Comment: I found an online OCR tool that did the job. Thanks again.